# Any issues using BI and Project Server together on a SP2016 Farm?

Tags: project-server, business-intelligence

We have a consulting vendor suggesting that the Farm NOT contain both BI and Project Server due to issues they've encountered in the past (I think SP2013).

So I need to know if its "ok" to have the SP2016 "On-Prem" Farm include the BI and Project Server (Project Server Service Application, SQL Reporting Service Application and Office Online Server configured for BI).

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Server is fully integrated into SharePoint now. There's little reason to have a separate farm. As for BI, much of that functionality has moved into Office Online Server. Of course, SSRS hasn't changed. Depending on usage it may be appropriate to run SSRS on dedicated SharePoint servers within the same farm, otherwise run it on your designated FEs.

It sounds like you may have inexperienced consultants on hand.